# Best time/place to do cleanup in an iphone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I have a typical RSS style application . I want to delete all the stories which are more than X days old, So that i dont keep filling up users HardDisk with old stories . 
Now, I am wondering what the best time and place for doing such clean up would be ? 
Is applicationWillTerminate in the app delegate right place to do it ? Also I think  I would be using straight sql to do bulk delete rather than core data.

Answer (score 1):

If you use `applicationWillTerminate` to do your cleanup, be advised that you only have a certain amount of time to quit your application (I think 5 seconds). If you take longer, the app will be killed by the OS.

If it were me, I'd do this in the background after the new feed items had been loaded.